# @nuxtjs/i18n redirect to the available translations

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I have 3 languages on my website but not all the pages support all that three languages.

**Problem**: a user visits my website and from the URL he changes the prefix to a language that the page does not have a translation to, the page will load with the key's names so the page content will look something like this: `mypage_header` etc...

**What I tried :**

1- according to [nuxt/i18n docs](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/ignoring-localized-routes/)  there is an option to set the available languages on every page but the thing is: if the language is not available the user will be redirected to the `404` page, I want to change that, so **he gets redirected to the available translation of that page**.

2- There is an option called [Locale fallback](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/fallback.html)

> Summary: Use fallbackLocale: '' to choose which language to use
> when your preferred language lacks a translation

This worked with the problem that it changes to an existed language but the direction remains the same, so if I have an English translation for a page and the user changed the route to the Arabic version, the direction will not  change from `ltr` to `rtl` .

**Example:**

If the page has English language and the user changes the URL from `/en` to `/fr`
I want the user to get redirected to the English version of that page since it is the only available language for this page.
How can I achieve such a thing?

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
i18n: {
  locales: [
    { code: "en", iso: "en", file: "en.js", dir: "ltr" },
    { code: "ar", iso: "ar", file: "ar.js", dir: "rtl" },
    { code: "fr", iso: "fr", file: "fr.js", dir: "ltr" },
  ],
  lazy: true,
  baseUrl: "https://example.com",
  defaultLocale: "ar",
  strategy: "prefix_and_default",
  langDir: "~/lang/",
  detectBrowserLanguage: {
    useCookie: true,
    cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
    redirectOn: 'root',  // recommended
  },
}
```

Comment: You could probably try to set a fallback here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/locale-fallback/

Comment: @kissu Thank you for your reply, I just edited my question, I have tried it but I faced another problem with language directions.

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools? Is the state regarding `dir` correct or not (+check the DOM)? This may help scope where the issue is coming from. Also, can you replicate the issue in Vue? Could be helpful to give the Github issues a read to see if there is nothing open regarding this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Locale fallback](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/locale-fallback/) was the right solution, it was my mistake, in the translation files which are  `en.js`, `fr.js`, and `ar.js` : I was putting my translations in **mixed formats**:  `JSON` and `JS object` formats rather than putting it in either `JSON` only or `JS object` only,
changing all the translations format to `JS object` only, fixed the problem for me.

Comment: It could also work with JS but usually it's a JSON indeed.

Comment: @kissu mixing the formats was the mistake, it's  also working with ```JS objects```  as you said, but in my case there was some translations mix inside the same file some as JSON and the rest was JS object, that's why it wasn't working properly